# how to do multiple order by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing column: status and created_at, status only contains value 1 and 0, created_at value has `Y-m-d h:i:s` format. I want my data sort by value ascending, next if value 0 then sort by created_at asc, if value 1 created_at desc

```
select status, created_at
from table
order by status asc, (case
 status=1 THEN created_at desc
 status=0 THEN created_at asc
END)
```

my expected result:

```
status  created-at
0       2019-08-08 06:09:09
0       2019-08-08 08:56:09
0       2019-08-08 09:02:09
0       2019-08-08 09:09:09
1       2019-08-07 09:05:09
1       2019-08-07 08:50:09
1       2019-07-22 11:11:11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use separate cases instead of single.

Since we need both cases to work, So I have added 2 cases to make this work.

Give a try and let us know, btw `asc` is optional keyword since by default it orders by `asc`.

```
select status, created_at
from your_table
order by status asc, 
case when status=0 THEN created_at end asc,
case when status=1 THEN created_at end desc;
```

Comment: Adding some explanation as to how this works would make it a much better answer.

Comment: @Nick As requested, I have added.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of that the case expressions work because e.g. for the first one when `status != 0` its value is `NULL` and therefore it won't affect the sorting. So each expression only affects the sorting for that given value of `status`

Comment: Sorry,  my bad, will improve in future, I'm still learning from my mistakes, thanks for helping me out.

Comment: it works really fine, i got my expected result, thank you!

Comment: @WahyuKusuma If it resolves kindly makes the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this would work...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 ORDER
    BY status
     , CASE status 
       WHEN 1 
       THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)*-1 
       ELSE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) END
```

Comment: this one works really fine too, i got my expected result, thank you!